# While loop continuously looping comparing times

Tags: powershell

```
$time = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time
$addTime = Read-Host -Prompt "How many minutes until computer turns off?"

$addTimeConvert = [timespan]::FromMinutes($addTime)
$addTimeConvertOut = $addTimeConvert.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

$newTime = $time + $addTimeConvert


Write-Host $newTime
Write-Host $time

while ($newTime -ne $time){

   $time = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time



   }
Stop-Computer
```

I want to write a script to turn off my computer after a set amount of time but for some reason the while loop continues even after they are the same time.

Comment: Much better. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Would `Start-Sleep` not produce a lower-cost alternative? Running your CPU at 100% for hours is likely to increase your electricity bill...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than answer your asked question, can I offer an alternative solution to the (probable) original problem?

```
$minutes = Read-Host -Prompt "How many minutes until computer turns off?"
Start-Sleep -Seconds (60 * $minutes)
Stop-Computer
```

Comment: ahh yes that makes sense! i did not know about the start sleep !